# gmock: NiceMock and MockFunction

Tags: googlemock

I was wondering whether it is possible to use `NiceMock` together with `MockFunction`.

What I currently have is more-the-less the following:

```
struct ApiT {
  std::function<int(void*)> bar;
  std::function<int(void*)> baz;
  // ...
};

struct MockT {
  ApiT api;
  MockFunction<int(void*)> bar;
  MockFunction<int(void*)> baz;
  MockT() {
    api.bar = bar.asStdFunction();
    api.baz = baz.asStdFunction();
  }
};

TEST(foo_test, test_bar_is_being_called_by_foo) {
  MockT mock;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock.bar, Call(_)).WillOnce(Return(0));
  foo(mock.api); // foo calls bar and baz
}
```

Problems/observations:

- The test basically works, but I see an ugly "uninteresting mock function call ..." because there is no expectation on `baz`
- I tried with `NiceMock<MockT> mock;` instead of `MockT mock;`, but that doesn't seem to work, i.e. I still see the warning
- I don't want to state any expectations on `baz` being called as I don't care about it in this test
- I *do* need and want to mock `baz` as its original execution takes long and requires some setup
- I think I could change ApiT to use (virtual) functions instead of `std::function` and then use MOCK_METHOD and NiceMock. However, as the code already exists, I was wondering whether there exists a way to use NiceMock together with MockFunction.